# How to compile an application that uses libraries compiled from different compilers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, driver, mingw32

My question is as the topic.

I am currently using **Mingw32 compiler** in Qt creator to compile my application. The problem is that I include a **.lib static library** and header file which compiled from **Visual Studio 2017** in my application.

When I further run or compiled my application in Qt. I would be facing the error code, **unrecognized file format** pointing to the .lib file.

I reasonably doubt that: For example, I can not use compiler 1 to compile other libraries compiled from compiler 2.

I follow the instruction here:[libwdi Installation and Compilation](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/Install) to compile the "libwdi.lib" file.

FYI, the reason that I use Visual Studio to compile the .lib library(libWdi) is because it's easier to achieve on my Windows OS after I tried using wingw32-make from Qt5 Tool. It is such a pain since I can not even run ./autogen.sh to generate the makefile for Mingw32 on Windows.

Appreciate any step-by-step information on how to build a **workable .lib file** for Qt creator, including using **VS, mingw, and cross-compilers**.

Comment: You can't. C++ name mangling is not standardized but implementation-defined, which means that the C++ ABI is not portable across compilers, especially not when Microsoft is involved. That being said, your question is meandering a bit, so I am not sure if that is *all* you asked about.

Comment: A suggestion for who comes to here: Try to use a dll wrapper and compile it with the same compiler using by your desired lib. At least you can call it, but it is still a pain if there are many things need to wrap.

Answer (score 2):

If the target library uses c++ features in its public interface then it is likely this is not going to work regardless of what machinations you go through. Even different versions of the same compiler often have problems in that situation.

Pure C on the other hand will usually work (on Windows non-MS tool sets will be made to at least consume the MS intermediate object format, even if not used by the compiler/linker normally).

Comment: How to check if the source code uses pure c or c++?? If it uses pure c, how can I compile it from source?? tks

Comment: No choice but to examine the header(s), in particular look for namespaces, classes, templates and operator overloads. Less likely but still possible are structs with function members. Any of the above and the library uses c++ as part of its public interface.

Comment: *Good* sources should indicate this by the extension of the header file -- `.h` for C, `.hpp` (or similar) for C++. Unfortunately it is quite common to name even C++ headers `.h`, so you cannot really rely on that.